# Filter viewbag elements in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
Action Controller:
public ActionResult UserList()
    {
       ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var applicationDbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        ViewBag.Names = from u in db.Users
                    from ur in u.Roles
                    join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        //u.Id,
                        Name = u.UserName,
                        Role = r.Name,
                    };
         return View();
    }
View:
     @{

foreach (var Name in ViewBag.Names)
    {
        <tr>@Name</tr><br />

    }
    }
 Result In Browser:
                  { Name = accountant@healthcure.com, Role = Accountant }
              { Name = hasanaccountant@healthcure.com, Role = Accountant }
              { Name = assistant@healthcure.com, Role = Assistant }
              { Name = hasanassistant@healthcure.com, Role = Assistant }
              { Name = hasan@healthcure.com, Role = Doctor }
              { Name = doctor@healthcure.com, Role = Doctor }
              { Name = usman171@hotmail.com, Role = Doctor }
```

"But I need only that data where Role=Doctor.How can I do that either by change in query or filter viewbag result.My main purpose is to get Role and the associated users with them"

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewModel` rather like below. create a viewmodel named `TestModel` inside `Models` folder

```
public class TestModel
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Role {get; set;}
}
```

Use that view model to create a strongly typed view instead of creating an anonymous object and `ViewBag`

```
public ActionResult UserList()
    {
       ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var applicationDbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        IEnumareble<TestModel> models = from u in db.Users
                                        from ur in u.Roles
                                        join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                                          select new TestModel
                                            {
                                               Name = u.UserName,
                                               Role = r.Name,
                                            };

         return View(models);
    }
```

Create a strongly typed view with Model as `IEnumareble<TestModel>`

```
@{Model = IEnumareble<TestModel>}
     @{
       foreach (TestModel Name in Model.Where(m => m.Role == "Doctor"))
       {
        <tr>@Name</tr><br />
       }
      }
```

Comment: "The type or namespace name IEnumareble not found".This error is coming when i added blow code IEnumareble<TestModel> models = from u in db.Users
                                        from ur in u.Roles
                                        join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                                          select new TestModel
                                            {
                                               Name = u.UserName,
                                               Role = r.Name,
                                            };

  return View(models);

Comment: Hey, you need to add the specific namespace `using System.Collection.Generic`. If you would have search in google you would have not needed to post a comment here.

Comment: @user3515219, right click on the error line and select resolve (OR) presee `CRTL + .`. It will solve automatically.